# Units for Slurm sinfo CPU Load

Tags: slurm

I can see the "CPU load" for all the nodes on a cluster using the `sinfo` command:

```
sinfo --Node --format="%10N %.6D %10P %10T %20E %.4c %.8z %8O %.6m %10e %.6w %.60f"
```

The `%8O` in there asks for a measure of the CPU load that is eight characters wide.  The problem I have with this command is that the [manual doesn't say](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html) what the units are.  It just says "CPU load of a node."  Is this in percent? Number of processes per CPU? Number of processes per thread?  Equivalent number of fully committed CPUs/threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Linux context, the CPU load has a specific definition related to the number of processes being executed, or pending execution (i.e. requesting CPU but not having access to it.)

Often, the load average over a short period of time is considered ; that is why fractional number can be reported by the various commands that compute the load.

A load of 0 means no activity, a load of 1 means the equivalent of 1 CPU core being 100% active during the considered period, or two cores being 50% active, etc. And it can be due to one process being [CPU bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound), or two processes being [I/O bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) for instance.

A load larger than the number of CPU cores in the machine indicates that many process are fighting for CPU resources and [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) occur.

A load equal to the number of CPU cores in the machine indicates all cores are busy 100% of the time, and this is what is expected on HPC clusters. Most of the time in that case, processes are [pinned to their "own" core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)) for more information.